# Converting string to a collection of digits in Scala using map and toInt

Tags: string, scala, type-conversion, int

I am able to convert a single digit string to int using `toInt`:

```
scala> "1".toInt
res1: Int = 1
```

However, when I use `map` to iterate through the characters and convert them individually using `toInt` I am getting their ASCII codes:

```
scala> "123".map(_.toInt)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(49, 50, 51)
```

Why is that and is it possible to use `map` and `toInt` to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use `.asDigit` as within the `map` you iterate on `Char`s. Your first example works because `toInt` is applied on a `String`. `toInt` on a `Char` provides the associated ascii code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `toString` in your `map` function:

```
 "123".map(_.toString.toInt)
```

As *Xavier* explained an element of a `String`(-collection) is a `Char` - so just make a `String` again.

Or use as he suggested `.asDigit`:

```
"123".map(_.asDigit)
```

From the Repl:

```
scala> "123".map(_.toInt)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(49, 50, 51)

scala> "123".map(_.toString.toInt)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> "123".map(_.asDigit)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```